# How to upload mov files to Picasa Web?

Tags: picasa

The [help page](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=19496) says Picasa supports MOV files. I have the latest version (3.8.0 build 117.29) and the MOV files for a scanned folder aren't shown. How can I upload them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

1. Install QuickTime
2. Enable QuickTime in Picasa > Tools > Options

And if the folder was already scanned you have to rescan it

1. Rename the folder with Windows Explorer
2. Add it again to Picasa